# objective c, i want to use SWRevealViewController in my stroyboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json, xcode, storyboard

I am novice in Objective-C.I want to load left side meny . For that i am using SWRevealViewController  . [image]
but i am falied to load this my code

```
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

#define homePagesNews @"http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/topnews"
#define jatioNews @"http://198.72.115.125/~pratidin/api/categorynews/4"

@interface ContactsTableViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *res;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *contactsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *newsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *details;



@end

@implementation ContactsTableViewController

@synthesize contactsArray, details,newsArray;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

//    _barButton.target = self.revealViewController;
//    _barButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
//    
//    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    NSLog(@"My");
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"plist"];
    contactsArray  = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile :path];    
    [self GetHomePageData];

}

-(void)GetHomePageData{

    NSString *urlString   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",homePagesNews];
    NSURL *url            = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *GETReply      = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GETReply options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves|| NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",res);

    for (int i=0; i< res.count; i++){
        NSLog(@"item-id :%@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"item_id"]);
        NSLog(@"datetime %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"]);
        NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"summery"]);
        NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"main_url"]);
        NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"featured_image"]);
        NSLog(@"main_url %@",[[res objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"main_url"]);
        NSLog(@"----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
   // return [contactsArray count];
    return  res.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    details = res[indexPath.row];

    NSString *titleNews = details[@"title"];
    NSString *newsDateTime = details[@"datetime"];
    NSString *NewsImageName = details[@"featured_image"];

    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:NewsImageName ];
   // UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:NewsImageName]]];

    customCell.customFirstNameLabel.text = titleNews;
    customCell.customLastnameLabel.text = newsDateTime;
    //customCell.customImageView.image =image;

    NSURL *imageUrl=[details valueForKey:@"featured_image"];

    [customCell.customImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"]];

    return customCell;
}
```

SotryBoard images

[image]

It would be kind enough if some solve my problem . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is all wrong it seems.You should have a ViewController of `SWRevealViewController` class in the storyBoard like in this [tutorial_1](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/)  and   [tutorial_2](http://samwize.com/2015/03/25/setting-up-swrevealviewcontroller/).Go through these.

Then if you are using the latest version of [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)(version 2.4.0) ,then there are now two different segue classes, `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` and `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController`. The first one is meant to set the revealViewController with the initial controllers from the story board. The second one is used to push controllers to the front with animation.

SO you should connect the home screen with the above mentioned ViewController using `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` segue and should name it `sw_front` and you should connect the side menu with the above mentioned ViewController using `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` segue and should name it `sw_rear`

Thats it.Then make the ViewController (with class SERevealViewController) as the initial ViewController.

**Also,any segue from side menu viewcontroller should be of class** `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController`